# Substitute to grain mustard

Tags: substitutions, sauce

I am planning on doing a recipe of mustard sauce pork. Here is the recipe for the sauce (quantities are approximate, the recipe is *inspired* from a [Gordon Ramsay Youtube video](https://youtu.be/OsS21DdkpFw)):

**Ingredients**

- 1 tbsp vegetable oil
- 1 tbsp garlic
- 1 tbsp chopped shallots
- calvados
- chicken stock
- cooking cream
- 1 tbsp dijon mustard
- 1 tbsp grain mustard

**Method**

- In hot pan, caramelize garlic and shallots.
- deglaze with calvados, flambée if possible and reduce.
- Add about 1 1/2 cup of chicken stock and reduce by half.
- Add cream for richness and thickness, bring to a boil.
- Add mustards and let simmer for 5-10 minutes to meet desired consistancy.

This previous is the sauce of a more complete recipe but it does not depend on the rest of the dish to be a fine sauce, asides from the pork residue in the pan for taste.

Now the problem is, I don't have any grain mustard, but have mustard seeds at home as well as regular Dijon mustard.

Would it be possible to substitute the grain mustard by the same quantity of regular Dijon plus mustard seeds without compromising the taste too severely?

Comment: Hi, can you tell what the recipe is and list ingredients instead of writing _this recipe_? We shouldn't need to open a link or video when you can easily describe it here. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: @Luciano the question has been modified, thanks!

Comment: I would skip the mustard seeds and just use 2 tbsp of regular dijon mustard

Comment: Where does the recipe come from? It's not what he says in the video.

Comment: Some components are added assumptions. Such as the recipes and the final sauce simmering (I'm doing this to compensate the lack of letting the pork sit in the sauce and rest at low heat) The recipe is more specifically inspired by the video using the same ingredients. That is not the point of the question though. The question is the final paragraph.

Comment: But the recipe doesn't call for "old style Dijon". It calls for "grain mustard". Mustard *can* be both, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: MY bad, you are completely right. That was my mistake, let me modify, the question holds.

Comment: It is my considered opinion my answer stays valid even after your modifications.  **;-) :-) ;-)**

Comment: Indeed! But I want to try it before accepting any answer. I will not forget though!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, add the mustard seeds to the Dijon mustard and add a splash of vinegar, stir well and let it sit like that for 24h.

**For the impatient / I don't have 24h  ;-)**

Microwave the newly created mixture for one minute @ 750W (without the metal lid on!) and stir again after microwaving. (**Use oven mittens!**)